# Conditional probability, Are my answers right?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Hi there I just want to check my answer is wright, could you please help me ?

```
Customers are asked to evaluate hotels at an international hotel booking website. In the past, 95% of 
5-star hotels received good reviews,
60% of 4-star hotels received good reviews, and 10% of 3-star hotels received
good reviews. In addition, 40% of hotels at the website are 5-star hotels, 35%
of hotels at the website are 4-star hotels, and 25% are 3-star hotels.
1. What is the probability that a hotel on the website has a good review?
2. If a hotel attains a good review, what is the probability that it will be a
5-star hotel?
3. If a hotel does not attain a good review, what is the probability that it will
be a 3-star hotel?
```

My answers are;

```
Probability of a hotel on the website has a good review.
All the good reviews; 380 + 210 + 25 = 615
Pr (G) = 615/1000 = %61.5

2) Pr (Good | 5-Star) = [Pr ( Good ∩ 5-Star) ] / [ Pr (5-Star)]
[38/100] / [95/100] = 38/95  %40

3) Number of hotels with Not-Good review. 
615 out of 1000 has good  385 Not-Good 
Pr ( Not-Good | 3-Star) = 
[Pr ( Not-Good ∩ 3-Star)] / [ Pr( 3-Star)]
[225/1000] / [25/100] = 225/250 = %90
```

Comment: Your second and third answers are not correct. Second should be $380/615$. Similarly third should be $225/385$.

Comment: You have not defined your $P(B)$ correctly. For example the given condition in the second is that a hotel is good (not that it is a $5$ star) and that probability is $61.5\%$.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer @MathLover

Comment: OK I just added some details in an answer.

Comment: Thank you @MathLover

Comment: if 40% of hotels are 5 star and 100% of 5 star hotels get good reviews, why do you show 380 as 5-start and good reviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If a hotel attains a good review, what is the probability that it will be a
5-star hotel?**

If $A$ is the event of a hotel being $5$ star and $B$ is the event of a hotel attaining good review

$P(A \cap B) = 38\% \,, \,$ as you calculated in your first answer. That is $38$ hotels out of $100$ are good as well as a $5$ star.

$P(B) = 61.5\% \, , \,$ that is $61.5$ hotels are expected to be good out of $100$.

So $P(A|B) = \frac{38}{61.5} = \frac{76}{123}$

**If a hotel does not attain a good review, what is the probability that it will
be a 3-star hotel?**

Similar to previous one -

$100 - 61.5 = 38.5 \% \, $ hotels in total do not attain a good review. This is your $P(B)$.

$25\% - 2.5\% = 22.5 \% \, , \,$ $3$ star hotels do not attain good review. This is your $P(A \cap B)$.